# Is it normal that my unadvertised site with no search engine optimization can get 90 unique visitors a day?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

Im developing a web app and I noticed that the "under construction" that the url points to is getting a lot of views, and I was expecting basically none at the moment.

Is this normal? Are these just "bots" combing the web or something like that?

I included a picture of the data from google analytics.

[image: analytics]

Referrals:

[image]

Comment: Look into Aquisition/Referral reports and see if there are any strange referring sites.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff ! I did that and they all seem super strange, I'm adding another screenshot to the post, any idea whats happening here?

Comment: I see the one is some sort of ad business, are these just bots combing my site? Actual users?

Comment: Search stackoverflow for "referral spam" , this is a major problem and is discussed frequently (in fact so often that there is nothing to add to existing posts).

Comment: I'll do that, thanks!